# Looking for a user-centric plugin for Redmine/Chiliproject

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins, chiliproject

We need a plugin where you can view all the submitted tickets but tickets by the same author are folded together

And when viewing a ticket it'll show that persons prior requests.

Is there a plugin that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to create a customized search, grouping by person, on the Issues tab?